# PySimpleGUI/tk: drawing OpenCV image into sg.Graph efficiently

Tags: opencv, pysimplegui

An image captured from a camera is stored into a *numpy ndarray* object with a shape of (1224,1024,3).

This format is very convenient for using OpenCV methods over it.

I was looking for the way to draw it into (or onto) an sg.Graph element of PySimpleGUI.

The method I have found worked, but was very inefficient:

```
def draw_img(self, img):
    # turn the image into a PIL image object:
    pil_im = Image.fromarray(img)
    
    # use PIL to convert the image into an in-memory PNG file
    with BytesIO() as output:
        pil_im.save(output, format="PNG")
        png = output.getvalue()
    
    # remove any previous elements from the canvas of our sg.Graph:
    self.image_element.erase()
    
    # add an image into the sg.Graph element
    self.image_element.draw_image(data=png, location=(0, self.img_sz[1]))
```

The reason for being inefficient is clearly because we are encoding the raw image into PNG.

However I could not find any better way to do this! In my case, I had to show every frame coming from the camera, and it was way too slow.

So what is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any 'by the book' solution, but I have found a working way.

The idea came from a discussion in [this page](https://python-forum.io/thread-528.html). With it, I had to copy the original code of *draw_image* in *PySimpleGUI* and modify it.

```
def draw_img(self, img):
    # turn our ndarray into a bytesarray of PPM image by adding a simple header:
    # this header is good for RGB. for monochrome, use P5 (look for PPM docs)
    ppm = ('P6 %d %d 255 ' % (self.img_sz[0], self.img_sz[1])).encode('ascii') + img.tobytes()
    
    # turn that bytesarray into a PhotoImage object:
    image = tk.PhotoImage(width=self.img_sz[0], height=self.img_sz[1], data=ppm, format='PPM')
    
    # for first time, create and attach an image object into the canvas of our sg.Graph:
    if self.img_id is None:
        self.img_id = self.image_element.Widget.create_image((0, 0), image=image, anchor=tk.NW)
        # we must mimic the way sg.Graph keeps a track of its added objects:
        self.image_element.Images[self.img_id] = image
    else:
        # we reuse the image object, only changing its content
        self.image_element.Widget.itemconfig(self.img_id, image=image)
        # we must update this reference too: 
        self.image_element.Images[self.img_id] = image
```

Using this method, I could achieve a great performance, so I decided to share this solution with the community. Hoping this will help anybody!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me. I modified your plan.
my code:

```
def image_source(path,width=128,height=128):
    img = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')#PIL image
    image = img.resize((width, height))
    ppm = ('P6 %d %d 255 ' % (width, height)).encode('ascii') + image.tobytes()
    
    return ppm

image1=image_source(r'Z:\xxxx6.png')
layout = [.... sg.Image(data=image1) ...
```

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful. Welcome to SO!